# How to parallelize evaluation of a function to each element of a matrix in CUDA

Tags: for-loop, matrix, parallel-processing, cuda, multi-index

I am trying to reduce modulo p each element of a matrix, and I am wondering whether I got the specification of thread indexes for stride loops in two dimensions right.

Here is my kernel :

```
__global__
void gpu_matrix_fma_reduction(double *matrix, int rows, int cols, double u, double p){
  /* Reduce each coefficient of a matrix modulo p (with u = 1.0/p) */
  for (int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; i < rows; i += blockIdx.x*gridDim.x) {
    for (int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y; j < cols; j += blockIdx.y*gridDim.y) {
      gpu_fma_reduction(matrix + i*cols + j, u, p);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the call to the kernel :

```
dim3 threadsPerBlock(16, 16);
dim3 numBlocks( n*m / threadsPerBlock.x, n*m / threadsPerBlock.y);
gpu_matrix_fma_reduction<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(partial_matrix, n, m, u, p);
```

I get an infinite loop. I am not sure yet whether it is due to this kernel.

EDIT: replaced rows by cols in the function call.

Comment: ```blockIdx.x``` and ```y``` are the block indices that go from 0 to grid dimension. So you increment by 0 for one block.

Comment: a correct striding loop uses `i += blockDim.x*gridDim.x`, not `i += blockIdx.x*gridDim.x`.  And likewise for `j`.  See [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/).

Comment: I had this exact tutorial under the eyes yesterday and could not spot the difference !
I wish Dim and Idx global variables had different colors in color syntaxers.
Anyway the code now runs and end, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has been given in the comments:

```
__global__
void gpu_matrix_fma_reduction(double *matrix, int rows, int cols, double u, double p){
  /* Reduce each coefficient of a matrix modulo p (with u = 1.0/p) */
  for (int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; i < rows; i += blockDim.x*gridDim.x) {
    for (int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y; j < cols; j += blockDim.y*gridDim.y) {
      gpu_fma_reduction(matrix + i*cols + j, u, p);
    }
  }
}
```

The `blockIdx.x * gridDim.x` are not correct increments. The correct increment should be `blockDim.x*gridDim.x`.

Now, this is terribly slow, and a two dimensional loop is not the most adapted pathing for this problem. Since we only apply one function to each element, we can go through the matrix like a one dimensional vector. This would prevent jumps in index accesses, and memory can be better handled if it is accessed in the storage order :

```
__global__
void gpu_matrix_fma_reduction(double *matrix, int rows, int cols, double u, double p){
  /* Reduce each coefficient of a matrix modulo p (with u = 1.0/p) */
  for (int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; i < rows*cols; i += blockIdx.x*gridDim.x) {
      gpu_fma_reduction(matrix + i, u, p);
    }
}
```

The kernel call must be adapted :

```
int threadsPerBlock(256);
int numBlocks(n*m / threadsPerBlock.x);
gpu_matrix_fma_reduction<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(partial_matrix, n, m, u, p);
```